# Android ActionBar and Cursor

Tags: android

```
public class TaskDetailTabHome extends Activity implements ActionBar.TabListener{
String taskid, empid, ac;
private DbAdapter_Assignment assignment;


 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tasktab);

        taskid = getIntent().getExtras().getString("TaskID");
        empid = getIntent().getExtras().getString("EmpID");
        ac = getIntent().getExtras().getString("AC");

         ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
         bar.addTab(bar.newTab().setText("TASK").setTabListener(this));        
         bar.addTab(bar.newTab().setText("COMMENT").setTabListener(this));        
         bar.addTab(bar.newTab().setText("FLIGHT").setTabListener(this));        

         bar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM | ActionBar.DISPLAY_USE_LOGO);        
         bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);        
         bar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);        
         bar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

         assignment =  new DbAdapter_Assignment(getBaseContext());
         assignment.open();


 }
@Override
public void onTabReselected(Tab arg0, FragmentTransaction arg1) {

}
@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    if(tab.getText()== "TASK")
    {
        setContentView(R.layout.tasktab);
        Cursor c  = assignment.taskDetails(taskid, empid);  ??????????
    }

}
```

I am trying to pupulate the view with SQLite data. But the cursor is throwing an error(NullPointerException). The same cursor is working when I am not using ActionBar(tabs). what am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the problem is here :

```
assignment =  new DbAdapter_Assignment(getBaseContext());
assignment.open();
```

And more exactly here  `getBaseContext()` I think it's the only line where you can have problems (thinking of course that taskid and empid are not null of course) . Search for the exact use of getBaseContext() .

Comment: I changed getBaseContext() to this. Still same error. taskid and empid are not null.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. I guess you're working with tabs and not getting the right context. You should go up in the context until you get the last parent and try to get it done.

```
public static Context goUp(Activity current){
        if(current.getParent()!=null){
            current=current.getParent();
            goUp(current);
        }
        return current.getBaseContext();
    }

assignment =  new DbAdapter_Assignment(goUp(TaskDetailTabHome.this));
assignment.open();
```

Comment: Did not work for me. And crazy thing is cursor is working fine with other tabs just not the default one.

Comment: Ok. All I can think now is that you could try to set your default tab in the view. private TabHost tabHost; tabHost.setCurrentTab(TaskDetailTabHome.this);

Comment: I am using Honeycomb. Can I use TabHost ? TabActivity is deprecated for Honeycomb.

Comment: How about using diff layout in OnCreate and diff layout onselectedtab(default one) ...

Comment: Did that work? I've tried TabHost in a Honeycomb tablet and it works.

Comment: oh my, no as of now nothing is working. I tried tabHost :( Other all tabs are working and are able to get data. What else can I try to set it as default one....

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help you anymore, last advice, maybe you can create another tab for your cursor and do this one just the constructor work. Then select that one as your main tab.